# Difference between GUID and UniqueId

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, object-model

What is the difference between GUID and UniqueId? They are both globally unique ids and from the client side we can see they are not the same:

```
ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
web = ctx.get_web();
list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Issues");
item = list.getItemById(1);
ctx.load(item);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() { 
  console.log("GUID: " + item.get_item("GUID").toString());
  console.log("UniqueId: " + item.get_item("UniqueId").toString());
  console.log("ID: " + item.get_item("ID").toString());
});
```

Results in:

```
GUID: d2bcec49-5e88-494a-a141-4f4275363d79
UniqueId: 98237e32-67aa-4f95-887c-7567d0ab714e
ID: 1
```

Server side has [SPList.GetItemByUniqueId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.getitembyuniqueid%28v=office.14%29.aspx) so does that mean generally UniqueId should be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd961684(v=office.12).aspx.

> Guid 
>  Specifies a user-customizable unique identifier of an item.
>
> UniqueId  
> Document Lookup to GUID  
> Lookup to a GUID for an item.